# Deleting Semi-blank records in Excel through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete rows in VBA which are not completely blank. The reason I say this is because I am not able to apply conditions for perfectly blank like my first column is never blank and I want to filter on the second column.

```
lastrow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For i = 1 To Counter
If ActiveCell = "" Then
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Counter = Counter - 1
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Next i

   ( Given Info )                    Desired Result

Name   ID   Address                   Name   ID   Address
John        NYC                       Jack   55   Chicago
Jack   55   Chicago                   Kate   65   Boston
Kate   65   Boston                    
Mike        London
```

Now the offset will always traverse to the next row but how do I delete the entire row if the second column of a row is blank. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you start with the active cell being cell B2 instead of A2?  This would make the code work at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `.AutoFilter` can display only the rows to delete.

```
Sub nuke_Blank_Bs()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            If .AutoFilter Then .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
            With .Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then _
                    .EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

That will filter for blank entries in column B and delete the entire rows if entries are found.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this. You loop through each cell in column A, from the highest numbered row to cell A1 and if the cell in the same row in column B is blank, it deletes the column.

Note: I took out the `Activate` and `Select`. They are not necessary and will slow down your code.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Range("b" & i) = "" Then
        Range("b" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could use this:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim blank_Bs As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set blank_Bs = Range("b1:b" & Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If Not blank_Bs Is Nothing Then _
      blank_Bs.EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: The `xlCellTypeBlanks` is best but you should provide a safety check to make sure there are blank cells before attempting to delete them.

Comment: Edited for safety check.

Comment: I don't believe `.Count` is appropriate on `xlCellTypeBlanks` when there is nothing to count. Setting a range type variable to the `.SpecialCells` and determining if that var is nothing might be better.

Comment: Coincidentally enough, I just ran into this today and thought of this thread. [The .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) VBA function does not work as expected in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/832293). Discusses a maximum of 8192 non-contiguous cells that can be selected. Relevant to Excel 2003/2007 from what the article states.